# Java Arrays.Sort(arr, comparator); does not accept arguments

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Can't sort multidinensional array.

```
static int ccheck[][] = new int[6*6*6][4];

    Comparator<Integer[]> comp = new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] t, Integer[] t1) {
            Integer in1 = t[3];
            Integer in2 = t1[3];
            return in1.compareTo(in2);                
        }
    };
    Arrays.sort(ccheck, comp);
```

causes

```
error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.Arrays.sort
```

Comment: An `int[]` is not an `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
static Integer ccheck[][] = new Integer[6*6*6][4];

    Comparator<Integer[]> comp = new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
    @Override
    public Integer compare(Integer[] t, Integer[] t1) {
        Integer in1 = t[3];
        Integer in2 = t1[3];
        return in1.compareTo(in2);                
        }
    };
    Arrays.sort(ccheck, comp);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. You need to make all the `int`s `Integer`s instead. Otherwise you're invoking `compareTo()` on an `int`.

Comment: This will not compile